# How to change gst-launcher-1.0 code to opencv code

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I'm struggled with make gstreamer live streaming from raspberry pi to windows.
I want to change windows gst-launcher-1.0 code to python opencv code.

[SENDER in raspberry pi]

```
raspivid -n -t 0 -rot 270 -w 960 -h 720 -fps 30 -b 6000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -e -vvvv fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=5 ! udpsink host=PC_IP port=5000
```

[RECEIVER in windows]

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false
```

Can anyone help me how to use this RECEIVER in Python OpenCV?
Any help much appreciated! Thank you :)